# >adb shell su, not getting root permission

Tags: android, shell, adb, command-prompt, root

I'm trying to retrieve my files from my phone with a broken screen. adb is installed and device is already rooted. Trying to get root access on adb shell but it isnt working, cannot list folders in /data/.

Here is the command prompt

> C:>adb root
>   restarting adbd as root
>   C:>adb devices
>   List of devices attached
>   5024b403        device
>   C:>adb shell
>   shell@hlte:/ $ su
>   1|shell@hlte:/ $

From what i know the $ sign is supposed to turn into # sign signifying that i have root access, but it is not working, any fixes? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. I tried it on my other phone and it was due to the superuser app popping up a notification to allow the computer root access, sadly I could not see the popup and tap it on the phone with a broken screen

Answer (score 0):

My root mode was set to grant access automatically but shell was not getting root access. Switched to promt and I got a popup and when I granted the permission su worked.